# OpenCV 3.1 drawContours '(-215) npoints > 0'

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm trying to create a mask from a contour, but am getting a C++ error.

Using OS X Yosemite, Python 2.7.10, OpenCV 3.1.0.

```
def create_mask(img, cnt):
    '''Create a mask of the same size as the image
       based on the interior of the contour.'''
    mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), np.uint8)
    print("create_mask, cnt=%s" % cnt)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    return mask

print("Creating mask from contour %s, on raw shape %s" % (page_contour, raw.shape))
page_mask = create_mask(raw, page_contour)
```

Output (see bottom for error):

```
Creating mask from contour [[ 1626.   360.]
 [ 1776.  3108.]
 [  126.  3048.]
 [  330.   486.]], on raw shape (3840, 2160, 3)
create_mask, cnt=[[ 1626.   360.]
 [ 1776.  3108.]
 [  126.  3048.]
 [  330.   486.]]
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (npoints > 0) in drawContours, file /tmp/opencv320160309-92782-1efch74/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp, line 2380
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./books.py", line 209, in <module>
    page_mask = create_mask(raw, page_contour)
  File "./books.py", line 123, in create_mask
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.error: /tmp/opencv320160309-92782-1efch74/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp:2380: error: (-215) npoints > 0 in function drawContours
```

The [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc&gsc.tab=0) say it should get an array of arrays and this is seemingly what I'm giving it. So what's wrong?

Code is ported from OpenCV 2.x.

Answer (score 26):

I think you are adding extra `[]` around `cnt`
it should be

```
cv2.drawContours(mask, cnt, 0, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```

as `cnt` is already array of array but `[cnt]` is array of array of arrays which won't work

---

**Update to the above code**

you should convert your contour to numpy array first

```
ctr = numpy.array(cnt).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(numpy.int32)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [ctr], 0, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```

check documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html#gsc.tab=0)

> contours is a Python list of all the contours in the image. Each
>   individual contour is a Numpy array of (x,y) coordinates of boundary
>   points of the object.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives the same error. Turning `cnt` into None avoids the crash but removes the semantics.

Comment: Hi I got the above error, when removed brackets from cnts, I now get : <built-in function drawContours> returned NULL without setting an error , do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting this because I did not know I had to convert to int. What a cryptic error message. I guess it makes sense in hindsight, but I wasted so much time one this

Answer (score 21):

For me this worked. But I'm not sure why.

`cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt.astype(int)], 0, (0, 255, 0), -1)`

When you get an array of rounded floats from findContours, drawContours doesn't complain. But when I construct a similar (4,2) array of floats myself, it complains.

Comment: This is true! But why? Anyone more experienced with numpy who can explain this?

Comment: `uint64` and `int32` also works. The latter will take up the least space, compared to the above choice of `int` as well.

Answer (score 5):

You might have commited mistake while finding the contours. Contour is the second value returned by `findContours()` function as the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) say

```
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

So the following code will not work

```
cnt = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

This might solve your problem.

Comment: In version 4.4.0 of cv2, the first parameter is the contours. The cv2.findContours and cv2.normalize break backwards compatibility with OpenCV 2.4.X.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use this, it will work...

```
ctr = np.array(cnt).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [ctr], -1, 255, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a numpy array so it will not work this way.
Make sure you add this to your code
`np.array(loop variable).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32)`
This works well.

Answer (score 0):

This error will also occur if the data type of the numpy array passed into the drwaContours function is not `int64`. This data type error might occur if you apply a transformation to the points in the contour, which changes their dtype. To correct for this error, be sure to convert the contour data type to int64.

```
new_contour = old_contour_wrong_dtype.dtype('int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by the wrong shape of the contour,  reshape the contour with `ct.reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32)`, then it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to draw the hierarchy instead of the contours.
The return of findContours is contours, hierarchy not img, contours,hierarchy.
Therefore, your

```
img, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

should actually be contours,

```
hierarchy= cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE).
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

its hierarchy, contours so:

`contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`